# display running services in web page

Tags: c#, command-line

I have a need to be able to grab services from a server and display them in a web page for testers to check instead of having them log into the remote server, open up services and check for specific services.

I've looked at a bunch of ways of doing it in the command line using tasklist, sc query, and even a get-service in powershell.

What I'd like to do is hit the remote server and display the running servives in a webpage.  Is it possible to do this from a c# page?

Comment: is your server is window based ?

Comment: have you checked the updated code? just paste it in the `Page_Load event` and try

Comment: Yes, the machine is Windows based.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `ServiceController.GetServices()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a.aspx

This will allow you to get a list of all the services on a machine. There's an overload that takes a machine name as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s21fd6th.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the help of [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can use `System.Management` namespace and try with following code by browsing [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("InstallDate");
dt.Columns.Add("State");
dt.Columns.Add("ServiceType");

try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();               

        dr["Name"] = queryObj["Name"];
        dr["InstallDate"] = queryObj["InstallDate"];
        dr["ServiceType"] = queryObj["ServiceType"];
        dr["State"] = queryObj["State"];

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (ManagementException ex)
{
    //"An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message;
}
```

Comment: So I can just drop this in the aspx.cs into the Page_Load event?  I've never seen ManagementObjectSearcher before.

Comment: Got this to work to display correctly.  What I'm curious to know is can I direct it to multiple servers to look for specific services?  I'm assuming I can limit the rows added by checking for specific Name before I dt.Rows.Add.  how can I change the search to a remote machine?